# setState not being triggered

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code

```
 setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({loading: true});
    }, 0);
   axos.post("....")
```

setState is not being triggered for some reason. Can someone please help?

Here's the code

```
submit(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({loading: true});
    }, 0);

    const {email, password} = ev.target.elements;

  app.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);
    // As httpOnly cookies are to be used, do not persist any state client side.
    app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(user => {
        // Get the user's ID token as it is needed to exchange for a session cookie.
        app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({loading: true});
                return user.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
                    // Session login endpoint is queried and the session cookie is set.
                    // CSRF protection should be taken into account.
                    const csrfToken = Utils.getCookie('csrfToken');
                    return this.postIdTokenToSessionLogin('/auth/session-login', idToken, csrfToken, "auth");
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({error: "There was an error", loading: false});
            }
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        this.setState({error: error.message, loading: false});
    })
}
```

Comment: You probably didn't binded your handler to your component's instance. It's hard to guess without a full example

Comment: Need more context to understand what's going on...

Comment: @Dupocas  I added more code

Comment: Are you using `constructor` to `bind` `submit` to your instance? A quick way to fix that is to turn `submit` into an `arrow function`. Like this: `submit = e => {}`. Since arrow functions have lexical `this` you don't need to worry about accessing the correct value for `this`

Comment: can you give me an example? I don't understand what you mean by turning it into an arrow function.

Comment: I'll post as an answer

Comment: Here's the code I use   `<form onSubmit={this.submit} className="Signin Auth Main">`

Comment: Unrelated, but please see the bottom of [What are tags, and how should we use them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging); putting explicit tags in the title is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `class methods` we should `bind` them in `constructor` first. This has to do with how `this` works in javascript. When accessing `this` from inside `submit` it actually refers to `submit` and not to your `Component`. Either `bind` like this

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
    }

    submit(e){
        //now this refers to Foo's instance
    }
}
```

Or you can use `arrow functions` which have a `lexical this`

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
    submit = e =>{
        //here this already refers to Foo's instance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({loading: true});
}, 0);
```

Calling `setTimeout` with 0 doesn't mean that the callback is processed immediately.

The callback won't be processed until the call stack is empty.

The following code illustrates this: (you will first see the values from the loop, and only after you will see `now`)

```js
setTimeout(function() { 
    console.log('now');
}, 0);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you need to either bind the submit in the constructor, define it as an arrow function, or call it inline with a callback arrow function.

Defining as an arrow function the is often the 'easiest' way but all will work in this case

Change:

```
submit(ev) {
    /* submit code*/
}
```

To:

```
submit = (ev) =>{
    /* submit code*/
}
```

Then you can use by simply adding as a prop such as to a button:

```
<button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Click Me</button>
```

Or inline arrow function:

```
<button onClick={(ev)=>this.onSubmit(ev)}>Click Me</button>
```

**Additionally:**

You need to update loading state once you have a user:

```
if (user) {
    this.setState({loading: false});
    //...rest of code
}
```

Keep in mind that neither setTimeout nor setState are applied directly but go into the queue (You are adding the setTimeout to the queue and when the setTimeout gets called you are then adding the setState to the queue further delaying the setState).

If you need to ensure that code happens after a setState call you should provide a callback function:

```
setState((prevState)=>{
   return {someState}
},()=>{
   //code to execute after setState is executed
})
```

**In my Opinion:** you  may instead want to initialize your user state to be:

```
state={
   user:{notLoaded:true}
}
```

Then in your auth flow use `setState({user})` if there is a user, `setState({user:null})` when no user is found, and `setState({user:{error})` if there is an error.

This reduces the complexity of state management without the need for separate error/loading states and then in your render function:

```
if(!user)
    return <LoginComponent/>
if(user.notLoaded)
    return <LoadingComponent/>
if(user.error)
    return <ErrorComponent/>

//we have a user!
return <UserComponent />
```